# Maintaing a sorted list of elements with random access

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

Given a list of unordered numbers with duplicates and another list of number with the indices. Find the number which appears in sorted order at that given index.

We should only consider the input only up to the point of the index of `index` array we are currently on.

If we are considering the element `2` in the `index` array we should look for the 2nd sorted element in the input array `3 7 9 10`

```
I/P   => 3 7 9 10 1 2
Index => 1 1 3  2 5 1

The output should be 

3 3 9 7 10 1
```

Ex. element `5` in the Index array will have corresponding sorted input array as `1 3 7 9 10` so the 5th element is `10`

My solution was to use  [multiset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) and then use `advance` to find the nth index in the set.

```
For i : [1 : len(I/P)]
   set.add(I/P[i])
   advance(I/P, Index[i])
   print
```

But the problem is set doesn't support random access and `advance` degrades to linear time.

How do i solve this in `N Log(n)`

Comment: If you maintain a binary search tree with child counts for each element, you should be able to find the desired in-order element in log(n) time.

Comment: Make sure that your BST is balanced, else your algorithm will go to O(n^2) in worst case. Consider an array having 10^5 elements from `[1 , 2 .... , 10^5 , 99999]`. Technically it's almost sorted which does satisfy `given a list of unordered elements`.